# Time not correct in "Device explorer" (device manager ; android studio)

Tags: android, time, android-virtual-device

I use android studio ans run app on AVD.
when I explore the data inside AVD, I notice that the time of creation of my database is 1 hour before the actual time.

does anyone enconter this problem ? any solution to solve it ?

I tried to change the time zone, but no success